# Better way to use ArraySlice with Accelerate functions?

Tags: arrays, swift, accelerate-framework, vdsp

I have some very large arrays that I have to perform millions of computations on. In Objective-C, the arrays would be stored as NSData and I'd abstract them to C arrays to use the Accelerate functions on (sum, add, etc). However, (given the obvious issues with using pointers everywhere) I'd love to make more use of the bounds checking that Swift arrays have built in. Therefore, I could use a nested withUnsafeBufferPointer for working with two arrays.

```
func mult(_ x: ArraySlice<Double>, _ y: ArraySlice<Double>) -> [Double] {
    assert(x.count == y.count)

    var results = [Double](repeating:0, count: x.count)

    x.withUnsafeBufferPointer({xBuffer in
        y.withUnsafeBufferPointer({yBuffer in
            vDSP_vmulD([Double](xBuffer), 1, [Double](yBuffer), 1, &results, 1, vDSP_Length(xBuffer.count))
        })
    })

    return results
}

var testArray = [Double]([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
var testArray2 = [Double]([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2])

let results = mult(testArray[5...10], testArray2[5...10])
print("\(results)")
```

First, having the recast the pointer as the intended type seems strange, when the compiler already knows how to cast the [Double] itself (the pointer passed inside the block is of type `UnsafeBufferPointer<Double>`, whereas the vDSP function is expects `UnsafePointer<Double>` (again, there is no complaint if I passed it the array variable itself)). Second, having to nest the `withUnsafeBufferPointer` looks strange, although I understand the usage. Finally, if I use `ArraySlice<Double>` as the input parameter type, then I can't generalize the function to both a Double array and a slice of that array.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The recast is indeed a problem, it creates a whole new array. To avoid it you can use the `baseAddress` property of the `UnsafeBuffer` (and unwrap it in Swift 3)
2. The nested `withUnsafeBufferPointer` are indeed correct and can't be avoided (to my knowledge). The buffer pointer is only valid within the closure.
3. You can create a protocol for that

All in all, here is your code with these changes:

```
import Accelerate

protocol ArrayType {
    associatedtype Element
    var count : Int { get }
    func withUnsafeBufferPointer<R>(_ body: @noescape (UnsafeBufferPointer<Element>) throws -> R) rethrows -> R
}

extension Array : ArrayType {}
extension ArraySlice : ArrayType {}
extension ContiguousArray : ArrayType {}

func mult<A : ArrayType where A.Element == Double>(x: A, y: A) -> [Double] {
    assert(x.count == y.count)

    var result = [Double](repeating: 0, count: x.count)

    x.withUnsafeBufferPointer { x in
        y.withUnsafeBufferPointer { y in
            vDSP_vmulD(x.baseAddress!, 1, y.baseAddress!, 1, &result, 1, vDSP_Length(x.count))
        }
    }

    return result
}

var testArray1 : [Double] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var testArray2 : [Double] = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]

let results = mult(x: testArray1[5...10], y: testArray2[5...10])
print("\(results)")
```

The forced unwrap will be fine, since the three conforming types won't ever give you a null pointer.

Comment: I should've thought of the protocol (I kept trying different ways of using the generics instead). One thing I'm confused by is why the protocol has to have `count` (the result array can't be declared without it, because it complains that `x.count` isn't valid), however it doesn't have to have `baseAddress`. Can you explain that?

Comment: @AdamJones It's because the `x` variable within `withUnsafeBufferPointer` is not the same as the `x` outside of it, it's being shadowed. If you ⌥-Click the `x` you can see it. I could've chosen `xBuf` instead of `x`, because it's an `UnsafeBufferPointer` which does have the `baseAddress` property.

Comment: I ran across a major hurdle with using a generic this way yesterday, that I still can't seem to work (cleanly) around. Using a generic for both parameters forces them to be the same type (Array and Array) or (ArraySlice and ArraySlice). However, I can't always conform to this, especially when nesting them, as the output is a `[Double]`, but the other parameter is likely an ArraySlice. And no matter how I mangle the generic list to accommodate, I can't get it to compile.

Comment: Never mind, after the 50th time I found `<A: ArrayType, B : ArrayType where A.Element == Double, B.Element == Double>`. It made no sense to use a comma in the where clause to me, I was just at my wits end.